# AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() in Facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I created a default MVC5 project and add my Facebook API keys;

Startup.Auth.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook;

            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
               appId: "id-here",
               appSecret: "secret-id-here");
```

Then I set breakpoint at ExternalLoginCallback method at AccountController.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
```

But, AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() only returns the
username and the email is empty.

How to set OWIN to include the facebook email?

Comment: Is this a bug on OWIN or Facebook?

Comment: please Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook -Pre after weill be solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solve after Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook -Pre.

so install from package console manager Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook -Pre and get facebook login info.